# how to start application when system boots using a .desktop file

Tags: startup

I searched and found out that I can make an application start while the system boots by using `Startup Applications` from the dash. But if I want to write a `.desktop` file, in which directory should I save the file and also what should be the contents of the `.desktop` file?

I found this code snippet from  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=<Name of application as displayed>
Exec=<command to execute>
Icon=<full path to icon>
Comment=<optinal comments>
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

If this is valid and works then what should I write in the `Exec`? 
The name of my application is `Albert`, which does the searching in the file system like you can search in `dash`. So writing `Albert` in the `Exec` is valid?

Comment: You'll have to write the full path to your programme, `Exec=~/Desktop/path/to/Albert` won't work, you'll have to write `Exec=/home/USER_NAME/Desktop/path/to/Albert` and so.

Comment: albert is in `usr/bin/albert`.  So according to you, `Exec=/home/username/usr/bin/albert` I should write this? And also rest of the codes I've posted are ok?

Comment: Exec=/usr/bin/albert is what you need.

Comment: And is there any specific directory where should I save the `.desktop` file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I did is, I created a file named `albert.desktop` in the `/home/<user_name>/.config/autostart`then I used the code snippet from below:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Albert
Exec=/usr/bin/albert
Icon=/home/<user_name>/Pictures/albert
Comment=Albert is an application that searches the file system like dash on ubuntu
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

And everything worked just fine!

Answer (score 0):

the following code works fine for me, startup the terminator terminal as soon as I logged in

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Terminator startup
Exec=/usr/bin/terminator
Icon=terminator
#X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true #this can be commented and even works
```